# How to set up a squid Proxy with basic username and password authentication?

Tags: http-proxy, squid

I currently I use ip in acl, and I want to use username and password to do this.

Comment: Here is another example how to setup Squid3 with a htdigest style authentication:
http://dabase.com/blog/Minimal_squid3_proxy_configuration/

Comment: here is a complete guide for Squid3 installation and configuration with authentication http://www.hevi.info/2015/09/install-and-setup-squid3-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-authentication/

Answer (score 235):

Here's what I had to do to setup basic auth on **Ubuntu 14.04** (didn't find a guide anywhere else)

### Basic squid conf

`/etc/squid3/squid.conf` *instead of the super bloated default config file*

```
auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid3/basic_ncsa_auth /etc/squid3/passwords
auth_param basic realm proxy
acl authenticated proxy_auth REQUIRED
http_access allow authenticated

# Choose the port you want. Below we set it to default 3128.
http_port 3128
```

Please note the *basic_ncsa_auth* program instead of the old *ncsa_auth*

#### squid 2.x

For squid 2.x you need to edit `/etc/squid/squid.conf` file and place:

```
auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid/digest_pw_auth /etc/squid/passwords
auth_param basic realm proxy
acl authenticated proxy_auth REQUIRED
http_access allow authenticated
```

### Setting up a user

```bash
sudo htpasswd -c /etc/squid3/passwords username_you_like
```

and enter a password twice for the chosen username then

```bash
sudo service squid3 restart
```

#### squid 2.x

```bash
sudo htpasswd -c /etc/squid/passwords username_you_like
```

and enter a password twice for the chosen username then

```bash
sudo service squid restart
```

### htdigest vs htpasswd

For the many people that asked me: the 2 tools produce different file formats:

- `htdigest` stores the password in plain text.
- `htpasswd` stores the password hashed (various hashing algos are available)

Despite this difference in format `basic_ncsa_auth` **will still be able to parse a password file generated with `htdigest`**. Hence you can alternatively use:

```bash
sudo htdigest -c /etc/squid3/passwords realm_you_like username_you_like
```

Beware that this approach is *empirical, undocumented and may not be supported* by future versions of Squid.

On Ubuntu 14.04 `htdigest` and `htpasswd` are both available in the `[apache2-utils][1]` package.

### MacOS

Similar as above applies, but file paths are different.

Install squid

```bash
brew install squid
```

Start squid service

```bash
brew services start squid
```

Squid config file is stored at `/usr/local/etc/squid.conf`.

Comment or remove following line:

```
http_access allow localnet
```

Then similar to linux config (but with updated paths) add this:

```
auth_param basic program /usr/local/Cellar/squid/4.8/libexec/basic_ncsa_auth /usr/local/etc/squid_passwords
auth_param basic realm proxy
acl authenticated proxy_auth REQUIRED
http_access allow authenticated
```

Note that path to `basic_ncsa_auth` may be different since it depends on installed version when using `brew`, you can verify this with `ls /usr/local/Cellar/squid/`. Also note that you should add the above just bellow the following section:

```
#
# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
#
```

Now generate yourself a user:password basic auth credential (note: `htpasswd` and `htdigest` are also both available on MacOS)

```bash
htpasswd -c /usr/local/etc/squid_passwords username_you_like
```

Restart the squid service

```bash
brew services restart squid
```

Comment: For me the htdigest command didn't work, however once I had substituted it for "sudo htpasswd -cd /etc/squid3/passwords admin" it did work as expected.

Comment: That's what I thought even if it did work for me. There was a discussion linked to this post with 50% of people saying it works and 50% suggesting a change to htpasswd. I didn't have enough reputation to  participate to the discussion though... :(

Comment: Thank you for downvoting my answer Joao Paulo Motta. SO is not a first level support type of system. If you need help you need to provide details around what didn't work, what you've tried exactly, error logs etc

Comment: worked for me, but I also had to use htpasswd instead of htdigest, I don't know why but in this way it worked.

Comment: @StefanoFratini You should update this answer to use htpasswd instead of htdigest. Squid manuals say it can be manipulated with htpasswd, not htdigest. http://www.squid-cache.org/Versions/v3/3.3/manuals/basic_ncsa_auth.html

Comment: This assumes that you use squid3. I am running Squid 2.7. If you do too, add `acl all src all` before the other acl in the conf. And the path being `squid` not `squid3` and the auth binary being `ncsa_auth`, the first line is `auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid/ncsa_auth /etc/squid/passwords` (remove the `3` for `htpasswd` too then). Hope this helps :)

Comment: @antoine129, Please suggest an edit to support both squid3 and squid2 and I will accept it. It's less error prone this way.

Comment: If your system does not have `htpasswd` please do `sudo apt-get install apache2-utils`.

Comment: I'm not even sure my answer is still actual @ospider

Comment: @StefanoFratini It's still working, however, on 16.04, the directory has been changed from /etc/squid3 to /etc/squid

Comment: This answer has a big mistake. Don't advice to use `-c` argument! It truncates old htpasswd file if it exists with old users.

Comment: Not surprisingly `-c` [creates the file and if it does exist deletes it first](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/htdigest.html).
 This is a common pattern with linux commands?

Comment: How do we generate the `digest_pw_auth` file?

Comment: after install, squid service ok, but I add proxy settings to firefox, it didnt work. alway asking authentication username and password

Comment: You may add below softlink along with above solution:
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/squid3/ncsa_auth /usr/lib/squid3/basic_ncsa_auth

Comment: I know this question is closed, but I had the same question for MacOS so I edited the answer and added the details here. I confirm it works fine on iOS :)

Comment: `digest_pw_auth` is now renamed to `digest_file_auth`