# How to configure username & password in tinyproxy?

Tags: authentication, tinyproxy

I want to restrict the traffic to tinyproxy, how can i do this by adding username & password instead whitelisting IP addresses?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Add `BasicAuth myuser mypassword` to `/etc/tinyproxy/tinyproxy.conf`.

Note that Basic Auth was added in tinyproxy 1.10.0, but Ubuntu 18.04 installs 1.8.4 by default.

Build the latest version of tinyproxy yourself or just use Ubuntu 19.04 or newer.

Comment: Thank you. Minimal "tinyproxy.conf": "Port 8888" "MaxClients 100" "StartServers 1" "BasicAuth myuser mypassword". Demo: "curl --proxy http://myuser:mypassword@localhost:8888 google.com"

Comment: Sample config https://gist.github.com/ericzon/b8d5201249544adf14b4280c890ae53f

Answer (score 4):

Currently its not supported in tinyproxy.

Here is an open enhancement request for that https://github.com/tinyproxy/tinyproxy/issues/29

Comment: start from 1.10, tinyproxy has shipped with HTTP authentication support.

Answer (score 3):

Although it's not nearly as small as TinyProxy, the [Squid proxy server](http://www.squid-cache.org/) would allow you to setup a username and password for your proxy. [This guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297196/how-to-set-up-a-squid-proxy-with-basic-username-and-password-authentication) shows you how to set this up.